# libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-3.6

Обновила версию Ubuntu до 18.04
До этого явно указывала путь до python3.5 в `.bashrc`

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5'
```

После обновления версия сменилась на python3.6, но при запуске приложения
он все еще пытается найти libpython в libpython3.5m.so.1.0

Comment: Не самое лучшее решение - хардкорить таким образом версии системных компонентов. Собсно я бы начал искать в `/etc` подобные костыли и создал бы нового пользователя, чтобы под ним посмотреть - ищется там старая либа или нет.